# Plotting of a Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, datetime, twitter, plot, dataframe

I am pretty sure you can help. I am just writing my thesis in social media mining and I am pretty new to this kind of stuff so please be patient with me ;)

I am doing a opinion mining on twitter, for that I have streamed a lot of tweets. i have then clustered the tweets for certain periods, for example: all tweets which are streamed between 01.12.2016 02:30:00 and 01.12.2016 05:30:00. And then i have analyzed the tweets to get a certain value which represents the opinion of the tweets of this period in sum. So each period gets a certain value. Now I want to visualize my findings, but i actually dont know how. Shouldn´t be to hard i guess. 
I have a dict (results) and two keys(date(datetime_object) and opinion(int)) in it. Now i want to plot a line chart where the y-axis is the opinion and the x-axis is the datetime.

```
results={"Date":[datetime_object1,datetime_object2,..],"Opinion":[235,158,...]}
```

I have no clou how to get the datetime objects into the x-axis.

Thaks a lot in advance!

Volker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data stored as a dictionary I would recommend that you just put it in a pandas DataFrame using pandas.DataFrame.from_record. You can then just plot the data using DataFrame.plot. Below is an example that creates a multi-index pandas DataFrame, resets the level and then plots the opinion vs datetime.

```
import pandas
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_range = pandas.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', freq='D')
results = numpy.random.normal(size=len(date_range))
opinions = [235, 158, 162, 150, 245, 132, 178, 200] * 4
numpy.random.shuffle(opinions)
df = pandas.DataFrame(results, index=[date_range, opinions], columns=['result'])
df.index.names = ['date', 'opinion']

# here I plot the opinion vs date directly, but you could
# assign a variable to it or the dataframe if you want to do fancier
# things with the plot
df.reset_index(level=1)['opinion'].plot()
plt.show()
```